# Implementing a "close" button in a OSX menu-bar app

Tags: objective-c, macos

My OSX app lives entirely in the menu bar, and thus does not have a conventional "main window" with a close button nor a standard system menu. The app was rejected due to lack of compliance with the [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html): "we have found there is no way to quit the app." Of course, the `Cntrl+Q` hotkey works, but that's besides the point. To clarify, here's what my app looks like: http://airgif.com/images/mordor.png

The question is: what is the preferred method for implementing a quit button in a menu-bar app? Is it sufficient to simply have a `NSButton` with the title of "quit app" somewhere within the app's settings?

Comment: so your app is a NSStatusBar thing? does it have any kind of menu in it at all? if not, how do users interact and/or configure the thing?

Comment: An image speaks a thousand words (note the "settings" icon tab): http://airgif.com/images/mordor.png

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is just to have a quit command at the bottom of the menu.

Comment: that's usual, yes, but Zane has now included an image of his app and it looks like there's no menu in that statusbar thing.  Just a sidebar of sorts.

Comment: I explicitly stated that I do *not* have a menu, and included a screenshot, and explained that I was looking for a solution that did not involve this.

Comment: @ZaneClaes: You don't have a traditional menu, but your app lives in the menu bar and you certainly have space where you could put a quit command. So I feel this convention still applies pretty well.

Answer (score -2):

From the Beginning of Time, Apple has enforced the Human Interface Guidelines.

A way for the user to quit the app is required.

After all, we don’t want OSX to look like some webpages with popups you can’t get rid of.